# Use of 'needs-lock' for an External file in Subversion doesn't work as expected

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I want some shared files to show up as Read Only when a working copy is created.

I am trying to set up a repository for several projects which all require some of the same files as a resource. I have set them up to be shared by using the External property in Subversion (actually I am using TortoiseSVN) The files are tagged at a specific revision for the property. That all seems to be working fine. Since the files are shared I want them to be locked which also works. However, I would also like developers to know not to accidentally edit the file. I tried using the 'needs-lock' property on the files so they would check out as Read Only. That works if I am making my working copy from the "real" source. If I have a working copy that used the External reference to get the file however it doesn't get created as Read Only and there is no way to know it shouldn't be edited until you try to do a commit.

I have been unable to find anything that explains use of locks with External files. Is there another way, maybe I missed something in my setup of the files? Thanks.

Comment: With TortoiseSVN version 1.7 or later the modified external files are separated in another changelist and can't be commited from the project that references this external, but apllying a `svn:needs-lock` in external files I'm afraid it's not possible.